# How to I make a line graph out of this?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

[image: How do I make this]

[image: Into this?]

I've imported seaborn and typed in this:

```
Bunker2019_Jan_to_Jun.plot(x='2019', y='Total')
Bunker2019_Jan_to_Jun.plot(x='2019', y='MGO')
```

and it shows two graphs. Is there any way I can show the year 2019(Jan to Dec) and 2020(Jan to Jun)?

Answer (score 0):

If you like them on the same plot, you need to combine the data frame, not very sure what is your "2019" column (date or string?), so below I tried to create a data.frame thats like yours:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mths = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', periods=12,freq="M").strftime("%b").to_list()
Bunker2019 = pd.DataFrame({'2019':mths,'Total':np.random.uniform(0,1,12),
                           'MGO':np.random.uniform(0,1,12)})
Bunker2020 = pd.DataFrame({'2020':mths,'Total':np.random.uniform(0,1,12),
                           'MGO':np.random.uniform(0,1,12)})
```

Simple way to add the year to create a new date:

```
Bunker2019['Date'] = '2019_'+ Bunker2019['2019'].astype(str)
Bunker2020['Date'] = '2020_'+ Bunker2020['2020'].astype(str)
```

We concat and melt, setting an order:

```
df = pd.concat([Bunker2019[['Date','Total','MGO']],Bunker2020[['Date','Total','MGO']]])
df = df.melt(id_vars='Date')
df['Date'] = pd.Categorical(df['Date'],categories=df['Date'].unique(),ordered=True)
```

So now it is a long format, containing information for both 2020 and 2019:

```
Date    variable    value
0   2019_Jan    Total   0.187751
1   2019_Feb    Total   0.091374
2   2019_Mar    Total   0.929739
3   2019_Apr    Total   0.621981
4   2019_May    Total   0.371236
5   2019_Jun    Total   0.027078
6   2019_Jul    Total   0.719046
7   2019_Aug    Total   0.138531
```

Now to plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df,x='Date',y='value',hue='variable')
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='Date',y='value',hue='variable',ax=ax,legend=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=65, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created the source DataFrame as:

```
      Month    MGO   MFO
0   2019-01   79.1  85.0
1   2019-02   69.9  91.2
2   2019-03   68.9  90.4
3   2019-04   71.1  87.0
4   2019-05   75.9  85.6
5   2019-06   60.9  82.1
6   2019-07   68.4  75.0
7   2019-08   75.8  60.7
8   2019-09   82.0  58.8
9   2019-10   95.3  56.6
10  2019-11   90.2  59.7
11  2019-12   86.5  57.7
12  2020-01   79.1  50.0
13  2020-02   88.9  52.2
14  2020-03   74.9  54.4
15  2020-04   87.1  51.0
16  2020-05   92.9  52.6
17  2020-06  105.9  53.1
```

(for now *Month* column as string).
If you have 2 separate source DataFrames, concatenate them.

The first processing step is to convert *Month* column to *datetime*
type and set it as the index:

```
df.Month = pd.to_datetime(df.Month)
df.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
```

The first, more straightforward possibility to create
the drawing is:

```
df.plot(style='-x');
```

For my data sample I got:

[image]

The second possibility is to generate the picture with smoothened lines.
To do this, you can draw two plots in a single *axex*:

- first - smoothened line, from resampled *DataFrame*, with
  interpolation, but without markers, as now there are much more points,
- second - only markers, taken from the original *DataFrame*,
- both with the same list of colors.

The code to do it is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
color = ['blue', 'orange']
df.resample('D').interpolate('quadratic').plot(ax=ax, color=color)
df.plot(ax=ax, marker='x', linestyle='None', legend=False, color=color);
```

This time the result is:

[image]